# Login Page with HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

**https://codepen.io/chris-arin-pine/pen/BaZmboz**

Edited to show login form:
https://codepen.io/boudra/pen/YXzLBN

```
<head>

    <title>Login Form Using HTML And CSS Only</title>
</head>
<body class="login">
    <div class="container" id="container">
        <div class="form-container log-in-container">
            <form action="#">
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <div class="social-container">
                    <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
                </div>
                <span>or use your account</span>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
                <button>Log In</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay-container">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
                    <h1>HTML CSS Login Form</h1>
                    <p>This login form is created using pure HTML and CSS. For social icons, FontAwesome is used.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Check the codepen. I have been trying to get the Login Form to cooperate with the existing CSS and they all clash.

Comment: Hi, can you explain a bit more on where the form should be placed?

Comment: you need to define columns or rows in your grid to make it properly aligned.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was trying to figure out the guidelines of Posting here. I need the login form to the right. I wanted them both centered on their own respective sides as a front login page. I'm learning js, css, html, php... and somehow this situation of clashing CSS is plaguing me. Hope you can help!

Comment: Think I may have found part of the problem. * {
  position: absolute;
}

*:before,
*:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
} was unattributed to anything and is applying to everything. Wondering if I can set it to an ID that only targets the witch landing HTML.

Comment: I think I'm getting closer. Might try the columns.
https://codepen.io/chris-arin-pine/pen/BaZmboz

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

Maybe it isn't the best answer but it is working perfectly.

I created the witch page with its own IDs and then IFRAMED the login form ontop of it. Unless I get some other solutions, it's kind of what we're going with.

EDIT: I used the iframe command in HTML to call a separate page, the one containing the LOGIN modal, and positioned it on top of the WITCH Landing Page so that the CSS did not clash. It seemed no matter what else I did the CSS would clash. Whether I wasn't closing } CSS calls correctly or # using selectors or ID correctly I don't know. I am learning. Might seem basic to some but for now I will iframe.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).